# Difficulties plotting confidence intervals onto 3d plot plane

Tags: r, 3d, confidence-interval, seq, errorbar

I have predicted values and confidence intervals that I want to add to my 3D plot using `trans3d`, but I get an error on the line that uses `seq` I already tried `length(z.bin)`, and read other possible solutions, but it's still not working.

```
Error in seq.default(lowerCI, upperCI, length.out = 25) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
```

I hope you can help me to fix my code. Here are the predicted values (z.bin), upper CI (UCI) and lower CI (LCI):

```
z.bin= c(0.0293498087331418, 0.090245714112389, 0.184180408140189, 0.288479689911685, 
0.380290727519617, 0.447221380019439, 0.486749948207999, 0.515460732539617, 
0.524544278048373, 0.517863012982977, 0.499015552138662, 0.471040830332284, 
0.436384769878271, 0.39696995466237, 0.354295721949241, 0.309542936297033, 
0.263681366413638, 0.217589473510825, 0.172201272125033, 0.128688774135519, 
0.0886552840745102, 0.0542241604227149, 0.0277504883386967, 0.0108213094005216, 
0.00277584412160996)

UCI=c(0.0366603230533126, 0.0902131425743432, 0.190710608825939, 
0.329281535177887, 0.37359325824382, 0.49083302601992, 0.502923852215148, 
0.532414036794941, 0.542594424500199, 0.544876477822669, 0.513975201348124, 
0.500360540087923, 0.460641689148807, 0.415363280410005, 0.358399020245284, 
0.321189810843667, 0.285678220416678, 0.234306786216362, 0.185151688725085, 
0.141800528101782, 0.0848830167493455, 0.0596895934068413, 0.034797331186028, 
0.0136423698337293, 0.00416130620917585)

LCI=c(0.0203880237502624, 0.0639803379126716, 0.15252099326726, 0.279883133515488, 
0.321969495145084, 0.433138773211774, 0.445700330934391, 0.474863237969827, 
0.485779389412345, 0.489219946727086, 0.461012139808171, 0.449297954511444, 
0.412682077834953, 0.370799794091489, 0.317884618001687, 0.283779930784182, 
0.251320227770169, 0.20400383106003, 0.158982316141284, 0.119627373509671, 
0.0683623411169277, 0.0464255905587446, 0.0252020843583765, 0.00810835262770212, 
0.0014811836711362)
```

code (please don't run the lines points() and trans3d(), res2 is not included, but it's there to show you the loop I want to use to create the CI bars):

```
    y.bin <- rep(1,25)
    x.bin <- seq(-10,10,length.out = 25)    
 #   points(trans3d(x.bin, y.bin, z.bin, pmat = res2), col = 1, pch = 16)

        for (i in 1:length(z.bin)) {
          lowerCI <- LCI
          upperCI <- UCI
          CI.bar <- seq(lowerCI,upperCI,length.out=25)
         # lines (trans3d(x.bin[i], y.bin[i], z = CI.bar, pmat = res2), col = #1, lwd=2)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to index the LCI and UCI values, otherwise you're feeding the `seq` function the entire lists:

```
for (i in 1:length(z.bin)) {
  lowerCI <- LCI[i]
  upperCI <- UCI[i]
  CI.bar <- seq(lowerCI, upperCI, length.out = 25)
  # lines (trans3d(x.bin[i], y.bin[i], z = CI.bar, pmat = res2), col = #1, lwd=2)
}
```